# Pusher send presence event to specific member

Tags: php, pusher

Is it possible to specify the member id of an event so that **only** that member would receive the event?

If for instance I want to send a notification to a user (who's user ID I know) how would I do that? I'm storing the member/user ID in the presence authentication -

`$pusher->presence_auth($_POST['channel_name'], $_POST['socket_id'], $user_id)
, $user_data);`

I want to be able to trigger an event for a specific user_id

```
$pusher->trigger( 'presence-test', 'test_event', $data, $socket_id );
```

Is it possible?

Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't send events to specific users/clients on a channel.

The best way to do this would be to have a [`private-` channel](http://pusher.com/docs/private_channels) per user so that you can send information only to them. The fact they're private also means that you can ensure only the expected user subscribes (see [authenticating users](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users)).

In your case the channel name can be `'private-' + user_id`.

You can then get the user to subscribe to that channel and publish to that channel from the server.

Comment: Does that mean if I have 1000 user's, I will create a 1000 channels!

Comment: And I want to send push notifications to 450 of these 1000 I will have to loop through all of them and make network calls. Wont that increase the overhead.

Comment: @Harshit, yes and yes it will result in increased network usage.

Comment: turns out you can pass an array of channels for the notifications, but that also is limited to 10.https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/interact_rest_api/