# How do I trigger an event to an individual only using Pusher?

Tags: php, chat, pusher

I program a chat using PHP and Pusher API.
Now, I'm trying to trigger an event to an individual user but I don't have a clue how to do so.
Every user is identified by a session (username).
This is how I trigger a message:

```
$pusher->trigger(
        'presence-nettuts', //the channel
        'new_message', //the event
        array('message' => $message) //the data to send
);

//echo the success array for the ajax call
echo json_encode(array(
        'message' => $message,
        'success' => true
));
exit();
```

I want to direct the event to the online user only, which is identified by his username using session.

Could you please guide me how to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pusher send presence event to specific member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591424/pusher-send-presence-event-to-specific-member)

Answer (score 0):

Your channel name should be unique to that user.
So, one possibility is to create a channel using something unique like the username:

```
$pusher->trigger(
 'presence-nettuts-'.$username, //the channel
 'new_message', //the event
 array('message' => $message) //the data to send
);
```